# How to show progress bar in display while executing method

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private bool ImportData()
    {
        bool result = false;
        bgw.ReportProgress(1);
        try
        {
            bgw.ReportProgress(3);
            intdevid = int.Parse(cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString());
            FetchDevicedata(intdevid);  // Fetch Remove Device Info from SQL database

            FetchMaxReportId();
            GetFTPFile(strDeviceIP, strDeviceUsername, strDevicePwd, strDevicePath + "//RunningBatch//RunningBatch.db", "RunningBatch.db"); // Copy RunningBatch.db to Debug Folder from Remote 
            LoadRunningData(); // Get Running Data in dataset from running.db
            if (DecodeBatchData_R() == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Running Batch Data Not Found");
            }// save in batch master and row data table
            bgw.ReportProgress(5);
            GetFTPFile(strDeviceIP, strDeviceUsername, strDevicePwd, strDevicePath + "//CompletedBatch//CompletedBatch.db", "CompletedBatch.db");
            LoadCompletedData();
            if (DecodeBatchData() == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Completed Batch Data not found");
            }
            result = true;
            bgw.ReportProgress(7);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsLogs.LogError("Error: " + ex.Message + this.Name + " || ImportData");
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    };
```

Button click event code

```
    private void btnimport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        label2.Visible = true;        
        dsCheckRptId = new DataSet();

        if (cmbDeviceName.Text.ToString().Trim() == "--Select--")
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Please Select Proper Device");
           cmbDeviceName.Focus();
           return;

        }
        if (cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue != null && cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() != "0" && cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() != "System.Data.DataRowView" && cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() != "")
        {
            if (ImportData() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Import Completed Successfully for " + strDevicename);
                clsLogs.LogEvent(3, "Data Import Completed Successfully for " + strDevicename);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Import Fail For " + strDevicename);
                clsLogs.LogEvent(3, "Data Import Fail for " + strDevicename);  
            }    
        }         
    };
```

Backgroundworker code

```
    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            ImportData();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

            bgw.ReportProgress(i);

        }
    }

    void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label2.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
        label2.Visible = false;
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Progressbar does not open when I click button. Please tell me how can I do this code open the progressbar in button click event. When `importdata()` executes, then progressbar open and when `importdata` finishes, progressbar should stop. Please give me some suggestion, how can I open progressbar?

Comment: 1. Your code formatting and text formatting is ugly. Could you please put some effort in it to make it more readable? 2. Which technology do you use? Is it WPF, or WinForms or ASP.NET? 3. I think that such common problem was asked and answered multiple times even here at SO.

Comment: your setting on every progresschanged the visibility from to ProgressBar to false. How should it be shown if your hiding it?

Answer (score 2):

Your setting the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx) of the ProgressBar everytime a ProgressChanged occured to false.
That means it is not visible anymore in the UI

Remove the Visible changes from your ProgressChangedMethod that should fix your issue:

```
void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label2.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

And then don't show it when the BackGroundWorker has finished:

```
void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
    label2.Visible = false;
}
```

**Edit(According Comments....):**

If you need a result from the BackgroundWorker, you have to give the return from ImportData to the DoWorkEvents.Result Property:

```
void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = ImportData();
}
```

And then handle it in the completed method:

```
void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = (bool)e.Result;
    if(result)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Import Completed Successfully for " + strDevicename);
        clsLogs.LogEvent(3, "Data Import Completed Successfully for " + strDevicename);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Import Fail For " + strDevicename);
        clsLogs.LogEvent(3, "Data Import Fail for " + strDevicename);  
    }    
}
```

Comment: thats then probably another question you want to ask because this one was about how to show your progressbar

Comment: your question above is about showing and not showing the ProgressBar when the BackgroundWorker is doing some work / has finished. Changing your code according to that what i provided should do that. If not you have some code which you haven't provided where you are doing something with the ProgressBar.

Comment: put `progressBar1.Visible = true;` before  bgw.RunWorkerAsync(); for the first. Then secondly why are you doing `if (ImportData() == true)` in your click ? this will be a second call to the ImportData method which will run synchronously and is for sure blocking your UI Thread thats why the progressbar is not showing correctly

Comment: yeah... as i told you that is another synchronous call that will block your UI if you want the result from ImportData from the BackgroundWorker use `bgw.Result = ImportData` and then handle this MessageBox in the `bgw_RunWorkerCompleted`